# review contact form before submission

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, input

need help... I want people to review their form input on a separate page then confirm their submission from the second page, how do i do this?

// index page

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uname">
    <input type="submit" value="next">

</form>
```

---

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["uname"];


echo('


<form action="submit.php" action="post">

// trying to prefill the form so that on submit the values are sent to submit.php
<input  value=$name name="username"> // setting the value to be captured in the next form = php variable $name


<input type="submit" value="next">

</form>
'


)

?>
```

Comment: How is mysql related here? You likely will be open to XSS injections here. It is unclear what issue you are encountering here.

Comment: Don't use `echo` like this. Instead close the `<?php` tag, flip back to HTML mode, and revert when you're done.

Comment: I think you need `if` statement: `if($_POST["uname"]!=null){echo("....");}else{echo "Invalid Input!";}`

Comment: @user3783243 am planning to post the input data to mysql database after the user has reviewed and confirmed that the data set is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep the preview data in a session. This is just an example based on your request.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uname">
    <input type="submit" value="next">

</form>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$name='';
$uname='';

$name = $_POST["uname"];
echo $_SESSION['uname'] = $name; 


if($_SESSION['uname'] !=''){

?>


<form action="submit.php" action="post">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="next">

</form>

<?php
}
?>
```